# Scopes for weekly calendar of events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

So I've got a weekly view of an event calendar, and I'm trying to cess out the best way to get the events that occur on each individual day.

Currently, my index action on the events_controller uses a class method on Event.rb to get all the events that occur during that week. However, I want to create a table that shows the events by day like this:

```
Sunday 04/29/2012
      Class 10:00 am
Monday 04/30/2012
      Class 10:00 am
Tuesday 05/01/2012
      Class 10:00 am
Wednesday 05/02/2012
      Class 10:00 am
Thursday 05/03/2012
      Class 10:00 am
Friday 05/04/2012
      Class 10:00 am
Saturday 05/05/2012
      Class 10:00 am
```

I'm not quite sure what the best way to get the events that occur each individual day out of my range of events occuring during the week.

```
#event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_week_starting(day=Date.today.beginning_of_week(:sunday))
    sunday = day.beginning_of_week(:sunday)
    saturday = day.end_of_week(:sunday)
    where(:date => sunday..satuday)
  end
end
```

EDIT:
Enumerable group_by seems to be the way to go. I can se up a weekly range and iterate through that, then use `@workouts.group_by(&:date)` to get a set of each workout, I'm just not quite clear on how I get the group out of group by that matches the date I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't end up using a scope, per-say, but here's the complete solution. It took a lot of poking around the console figuring out what the built-in methods returned, but after that putting together the logic wasn't too hard.

```
#event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def self.for_week_starting(day=Date.today.beginning_of_week(:sunday))
    sunday = day.beginning_of_week(:sunday)
    saturday = day.end_of_week(:sunday)
    where(:date => sunday..saturday)
  end
end

  #events_controller.rb
def index
  #use today's date if none comes through params
  start_date = params[:start_date] ? params[:start_date].to_date : Date.today
  @week = (start_date.beginning_of_week(:sunday)..start_date.end_of_week(:sunday))
  @events = Event.for_week_starting(@week.first).group_by(&:date)
end

#index.html.erb
<% @week.each do |day| %>
  <%= day.strftime('%A, %B %e, %Y')%></th>
  <% unless @events[day].nil? then %>
    <% @events[day].each do |event| %>
      <%= link_to event.name, event_path(event) %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```